# Event type for window:popstate in Angular HostListener

Tags: angular, typescript

What's the correct Typescript type for listening for a `window:popstate` event in an Angular HostListener? I've tried [`PopStateEvent`](https://angular.io/api/common/PopStateEvent)  but the structure of the actual emitted event is different from the provided interface.

```
  @HostListener("window:popstate", ["$event"])
  handleBrowserBackEvent(event: whatTypeIsThis) {
    console.log("popstate event:: ", event);
  }
```

Comment: It should be `PopStateEvent` from `lib.dom.d.ts`

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler That's what I thought but when I log the event in the console, it shows a very different structure from what's in the docs

Comment: what do you get ?